# How to check that the SparkContext has been stopped?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How do I detect whether the [`SparkContext`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) has been [stopped](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#stop())?

Comment: `sc._jsc.sc().isStopped()` where `sc` is `pyspark.SparkContext` instance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This applies to the Scala/Java API for that writing time**

Before Spark has released version 1.6, you wouldn't be able to check it, but only to trigger it:

`sc.stop()`

From version 1.6 and above, you have a boolean function that returns true if context is stopped or in the midst of stopping:

`sc.isStopped`

**This applies to PySpark API**

Thanks for @zero323 comment:

`sc._jsc.sc().isStopped()`

Which gives you the Java `SparkContext`.

Comment: Not sure about this answer....  I´m running spark inside a jupyter notebook. After the sparkcontext is created, if a manually kill it using spark UI, the notebook does not detect that the context is shut down

Comment: I don't think this method is usedfuk for pyspark, because once you stop sparkContext calling sc.stop(), the command sc._jsc.sc().isStopped() produces an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'"

Comment: Yeah, re: that, @harshlal028 I'm just using the kludge `sc._sc._jsc is None`

Answer (score 1):

If you use spark 1.5, that could be done via reflection API:

```
boolean isStopped(SparkContext sc) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field f = sc.getClass().getDeclaredField("stopped"); 
    f.setAccessible(true);
    AtomicBoolean stopped = (AtomicBoolean) f.get(sc);
    return stopped.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sc.isStopped`

Taken from https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala line 251

Comment: Worth mentioning it is available only from Spark version 1.6+

Comment: is it available from pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark, I just use the kludge `sc._sc._jsc is None` as an indicator for the context being stopped.

Bonus: if you're looking to see if a `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` instance, say `df`, is associated with a stopped spark context, you can do `df._sc._jsc is None`.