# What happens to the Spark context if the session is stopped?

Tags: apache-spark

If I stop an existing Spark session named `spark` with `spark.stop()`, what happens to its context? Is it automatically killed as well? I am asking because I took over some code where it says:

```
spark.stop()
sc.stop()
```

I wonder if I need the second command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [How to check that the SparkContext has been stopped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044450/how-to-check-that-the-sparkcontext-has-been-stopped) I found the method `isStopped`, and if I run

```
spark.stop()
spark.sparkContext.isStopped
```

it returns "true". Hence, it seems like stopping a session stops the context as well, i. e., the second command in my first post is redundant.

**Please note** that in Pyspark `isStopped` does not seem to work: "'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'isStopped'". I checked it with Spark Scala.